# Looping through ranges in different sheets (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets: 'Project_Name' and 'Admin'.

I also have a set of data on both. I have a code that attempts to loop through data in both sheets, but it does not work.

Code works if loop is only done on one sheet, but not both. I am not sure what the problem is?

```
Dim val1 As String
Dim val2 As String
Dim val3 As String

For i = 1 to LastRow

With Worksheets("Project_Name")
  .Range(i, 1).Value = val1
  .Range(i, 2).Value = val2
End With

With Worksheets("Admin")
  .Range(i, 1).Value = val3
End With

Next i
```

Comment: Disable screen updating and run 2 separate loops

Comment: deactivate it before loop and activate it again after loop?

Comment: What does it doesn't work mean? Is there an error? What happens? Also, where are lastRow and val1,2,3 assigned? And where is i declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and adapt the vars, it's work for me (note that .Range is remplaced  by .Cells) :

```
Sub test2()

' Active workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Integer

'*******************************************
'Adapt this vars


'define your sheets
Dim ws_pname As Worksheet
Dim ws_admin As Worksheet
Set ws_pname = wb.Sheets("Project_Name")
Set ws_admin = wb.Sheets("Admin")

'define your values
Dim val1 As String
Dim val2 As String
Dim val3 As String

val1 = "test_val1"
val2 = "test_val2"
val3 = "test_val3"

'definie the last Rows
Dim lastRow_pname As Integer
Dim lastRow_admin As Integer

lastRow_pname = ws_pname.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastRow_admin = ws_admin.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'*******************************************

For i = 1 To lastRow_pname


With ws_pname
  .Cells(i, 1).Value = val1
  .Cells(i, 2).Value = val2
End With

Next i

For i = 1 To lastRow_admin
With ws_admin
  .Cells(i, 1).Value = val3
End With
  Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT :** Code below to have only one loop.

```
Sub test2()

' Active workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Integer

'*******************************************
'Adapt this vars


'define your sheets
Dim ws_pname As Worksheet
Dim ws_admin As Worksheet
Set ws_pname = wb.Sheets("Project_Name")
Set ws_admin = wb.Sheets("Admin")

'define your values
Dim val1 As String
Dim val2 As String
Dim val3 As String

val1 = "test_val1"
val2 = "test_val2"
val3 = "test_val3"

'definie the last Rows
Dim lastRow_pname As Long
Dim lastRow_admin As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow_pname = ws_pname.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastRow_admin = ws_admin.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'*******************************************

'determine biggest last row
If lastRow_pname >= lastRow_admin Then
    lastRow = lastRow_pname
Else
    lastRow = lastRow_admin
End If


For i = 1 To lastRow

    If i <= lastRow_pname Then
      With ws_pname
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = val1
        .Cells(i, 2).Value = val2
      End With
    End If

    If i <= lastRow_admin Then
      With ws_admin
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = val3
      End With
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Does that mean I cannot do a single loop in two sheets?

Comment: If the last Row is the same cell on the both of sheet, you can  move With ws_admin
  .Cells(i, 1).Value = val3
End With in the first loop and delete the last loop.

Answer (score 1):

`.Range(i, 2)` seems wrong. Prefer `Cells(Row,Column)` when looping through rows/columns.

```
For i = 1 to LastRow

With Worksheets("Project_Name")
  .Cells(i, 1).Value = val1
  .Cells(i, 2).Value = val2
End With

With Worksheets("Admin")
  .Cells(i, 1).Value = val3
End With

Next i
```

Is working fine on both sheets on my set up.